# Implement textfield dynamically while receiving data (mqtt)

Tags: python, tkinter, mqtt

I am sending on an MQTT server (mosquitto) the data that I am getting from my DHT22 sensor. What I am trying to do know is to display the data that I am receiving (the data is always being sent to the MQTT server continuously) in a textfield and updating it each time the data is received.

Here is the TKinter code:

```
main=Tk()
main.title('sensor data')
main.geometry('700x500')
temp_label=ttk.Label(main,text='Temperature Readings')
temp_label.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,W))
temperature=DoubleVar()
temp_entrybox=ttk.Entry(main,textvariable=temperature,width=25)
temp_entrybox.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=(N,W))

humid_label=ttk.Label(main,text='Humidity Readings')
humid_label.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=(N,W))
humidity=DoubleVar()
humid_entrybox=ttk.Entry(main,textvariable=humidity,width=25)
humid_entrybox.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(N,W))

boutton=ttk.Button(main,text='connect',command=fon)
boutton.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky=(N,W))
```

Nothing too complicated just 2 textfields and a button named connect to establish the connection. The problem is in the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

temp = []
humid=[]

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("hi") # I did that to see if it is entering the on_message function and as expected it's not even entering it once.
    global t
    global h
    m=str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    t=m[16:20]
    h=m[34:38]  

#connecting to the MQTT server on my own topic.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("DHT22_cimti_project_pe")

# This code will get executed when the button is clicked
def fon():
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker)
    temperature.set(float(t)) #This should display dynamically the temperature in the textfield named "temperature"
    humidity.set(float(h)) #Same but for the humidity
    client.loop_forever()

broker="test.mosquitto.org"
```

The problem is that I get the following error:

```
Name t is not defined.
```

I did a `print("hi")` in the `on_message` function to see if it is even entering it and as expected it's not.

Comment: Don't tag things as python2.7 and python3.0

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry didn't know this could be an issue ^^'

Comment: temperature.set(float(t)) how are you getting the value of t? t is not defined in def fon() function

Comment: In the `on_message` function `t` is a global variable so it should be accessible from anywhere in the code. The problem is that the program is not even entering the `on_message` function.